# strip Unicode? hyphen and whitespace from string php

Tags: php, jquery, html, unicode

i am trying to grab a label value from a select list using jquery, write it to a hidden text input and then display that value in php template. --(there is no way to access the field directly in the data, this is my work around.)

so i can grab the label value, pass it to the hidden and display. BUT the label is formatted like so "  - latest news"
i want to strip the whitespace and hyphen/minus symbol so i am left with "latest news"

by trying the usual functions and them not working it occurred to me, when it didnt work that these may be unicode characters. when i use the following:

```
$mycategory = preg_replace('/^\p{Z}+|\p{Z}+$/u', '', $mycategory);
$mycategory = htmlentities($mycategory, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$mycategory = str_replace("-", "", $mycategory);

echo '<h1>'.$mycategory.'</h1>';
```

line 1 i replaced the unicode white space at the front. that returns "- latest news"
line 2: i changed the entity into html
line 3: i got rid of the entity. but that returns " latest news"

so i cant get rid of that last space with trim or the preg_replace. i have no idea how to get rid of it. if i put the blankspace in with the search term on line three it breaks the replace.

Comment: try pattern: !\W+!     untested :)

Comment: sorry, i dont know much about grep and not sure where you mean, at the beginning preg_replace or after the conversion to htmlentities...

Comment: preg_replace('!\W+!','',.....

Comment: almost. that also removed the space from the words latest and news though

Comment: Uhm... preg_replace('!\W\s!',''.. ? :) or \S .... damn, I need to refresh my knowledge in this one

Comment: lowercase s broke it, uppercase same result as the first replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,,,
grrr..had to open php :)

```
 $str = '- Latest news !*#';
 echo preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]\s]/','',$str);
```

Comment: THANKS for opening the php :-)!that did the trick. can you explain? was that unicode i was dealing with? and if it was, why didnt the htmlentities convert it? also, did it originally get unicode encoded or did that happen when i grabbed it from the select?

Comment: Actually. I just strip off ALL that is not a-z 0-9 and white spaces, so it really doesn't matter what is it inside, everything is getting wiped out :)